# ElasticSearch Synonym usage / syntax in my index

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

I am new to ElasticSearch.  I'm trying a simple genealogy project in ES and want to use synonyms for first and last names. I have the following ElasticSearch index setup and I wish to add two synonym analyzers to my settings and then use these two to do search-time synonym handing on different fields.  I don't know how to add the correct entries to my "setup" JSON file

My two synonym files are called **given_synonyms.txt** and **surname_synonyms.txt**.  I would greatly appreciate some help in getting the syntax right for this json file.

I have added (in caps) very generic psudo-code for what I want to do in the hope that it makes more sense to readers that way.

```
    {
      "settings": {
        "index": {
          "number_of_shards": "128",
          "number_of_replicas": "0",
          "analysis": {
            "filter": {
              "dbl_metaphone": {
                "type":    "phonetic",
                "encoder": "double_metaphone",
                "max_code_len" : 5
              }
            },
            "analyzer": {
              "dbl_metaphone": {
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter":    "dbl_metaphone"
              }
            }
    I ASSUME THE SYNONYM ENTRIES GO HERE FOR THE TWO SYNONYM FILES - BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW THAT SHOULD BE DONE
          }
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "test": {
          "_all": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "_source": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "properties": {
            "GivenNames": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index_options": "freqs",
              "store": "false",
              "similarity": "boolean",
              "norms": "false",
              "fields": {
                "phonetic": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                }
                I WANT TO USE THE GIVEN_SYNONYMS SEARCH ANALYZER HERE IN ADDITION TO THE DBL_METAPHONE
              }
            },
            "Surnames": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index_options": "freqs",
              "store": "false",
              "similarity": "boolean",
              "norms": "false",
              "fields": {
                "phonetic": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                }
                I WANT TO USE THE SURNAME_SYNONYMS SEARCH ANALYZER HERE IN ADDITION TO THE DBL_METAPHONE
              }
            },
            "FatherGivenNames": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index_options": "freqs",
              "store": "false",
              "similarity": "boolean",
              "norms": "false",
              "fields": {
                "phonetic": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                }
              }
              I WANT TO USE THE GIVEN_SYNONYMS SEARCH ANALYZER HERE IN ADDITION TO THE DBL_METAPHONE
            },
            "FatherSurnames": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index_options": "freqs",
              "store": "false",
              "similarity": "boolean",
              "norms": "false",
              "fields": {
                "phonetic": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                }
              }
              I WANT TO USE THE SURNAME_SYNONYMS SEARCH ANALYZER HERE IN ADDITION TO THE DBL_METAPHONE
            },
            "MotherGivenNames": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index_options": "freqs",
              "store": "false",
              "similarity": "boolean",
              "norms": "false",
              "fields": {
                "phonetic": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                }
              }
              I WANT TO USE THE GIVEN_SYNONYMS SEARCH ANALYZER HERE IN ADDITION TO THE DBL_METAPHONE
            },
            "MotherSurnames": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index_options": "freqs",
              "store": "false",
              "similarity": "boolean",
              "norms": "false",
              "fields": {
                "phonetic": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                }
              }
              I WANT TO USE THE SURNAME_SYNONYMS SEARCH ANALYZER HERE IN ADDITION TO THE DBL_METAPHONE
            },
            "SpouseGivenNames": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index_options": "freqs",
              "store": "false",
              "similarity": "boolean",
              "norms": "false",
              "fields": {
                "phonetic": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                }
              }
              I WANT TO USE THE GIVEN_SYNONYMS SEARCH ANALYZER HERE IN ADDITION TO THE DBL_METAPHONE
            },
            "SpouseSurnames": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index_options": "freqs",
              "store": "false",
              "similarity": "boolean",
              "norms": "false",
              "fields": {
                "phonetic": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                }
              }
              I WANT TO USE THE SURNAME_SYNONYMS SEARCH ANALYZER HERE IN ADDITION TO THE DBL_METAPHONE
            },
            "ChildrenGivenNames": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index_options": "freqs",
              "store": "false",
              "similarity": "boolean",
              "norms": "false",
              "fields": {
                "phonetic": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                }
              }
              I WANT TO USE THE GIVEN_SYNONYMS SEARCH ANALYZER HERE IN ADDITION TO THE DBL_METAPHONE
            },
            "BirthYears": {
              "type": "short"
            },
            "BirthLocations": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "DeathYears": {
              "type": "short"
            },
            "DeathLocations": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "MarriageLocations": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "MarriageYears": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "ResidenceLocations": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see the synonym analyzer and how you include the file.
From here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html you can see how you can configure that.
You mention two files. You are better of defining one file that includes or your synonyms.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "128",
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "dbl_metaphone": {
            "type": "phonetic",
            "encoder": "double_metaphone",
            "max_code_len": 5
          },
          "given_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/given_synonyms.txt"
          },
          "surname_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/surname_synonyms.txt"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "dbl_metaphone": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": "dbl_metaphone"
          },
          "given_synonyms": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": "given_synonyms"
          },
          "surname_synonyms": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": "surname_synonyms"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that when using a file (or multiple files) for your synonyms you need to make sure that every elasticsearch node has access to that file. Another way to do this is by specifying your synonyms in the settings section. This might be better if the number of synonyms is not very big or there are issues on making the files accessible to the elasticsearch nodes. You can check more ways to define synonyms in the documentation

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "128",
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "dbl_metaphone": {
            "type": "phonetic",
            "encoder": "double_metaphone",
            "max_code_len": 5
          },
          "given_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [ ... YOUR SYNONYMS HERE ...]
          },
          "surname_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [ ... YOUR SYNONYMS HERE ...]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "dbl_metaphone": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": "dbl_metaphone"
          },
          "given_synonyms": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": "given_synonyms"
          },
          "surname_synonyms": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": "surname_synonyms"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In order to reach a final solution, you can have something like this

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "128",
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "dbl_metaphone": {
            "type": "phonetic",
            "encoder": "double_metaphone",
            "max_code_len": 5
          },
          "given_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/given_synonyms.txt"
          },
          "surname_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/surname_synonyms.txt"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "dbl_metaphone": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": "dbl_metaphone"
          },
          "dbl_metaphone_given_synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "given_synonyms",
              "dbl_metaphone"
            ]
          },
          "dbl_metaphone_surname_synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "surname_synonyms",
              "dbl_metaphone"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this, you have three analyzers in total. Two of them are combining two filters (the output of the first is the input of the second, so order matters). In elasticsearch you can specify that a field will be analyzed with one analyzer during index time and when searched upon by some input, that input will be analyzed by another analyzer. So you can have this something like this (from here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html)

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So your settings/mappings becomes like this

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "128",
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "dbl_metaphone": {
            "type": "phonetic",
            "encoder": "double_metaphone",
            "max_code_len": 5
          },
          "given_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/given_synonyms.txt"
          },
          "surname_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/surname_synonyms.txt"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "dbl_metaphone": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": "dbl_metaphone"
          },
          "dbl_metaphone_given_synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "given_synonyms",
              "dbl_metaphone"
            ]
          },
          "dbl_metaphone_surname_synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "surname_synonyms",
              "dbl_metaphone"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "GivenNames": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index_options": "freqs",
          "store": "false",
          "similarity": "boolean",
          "norms": "false",
          "fields": {
            "phonetic": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone",
              "search_analyzer": "dbl_metaphone_given_synonym"
            }
          }
        },
        "Surnames": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index_options": "freqs",
          "store": "false",
          "similarity": "boolean",
          "norms": "false",
          "fields": {
            "phonetic": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone",
              "search_analyzer": "dbl_metaphone_surname_synonym"
            }
          }
        },
        "FatherGivenNames": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index_options": "freqs",
          "store": "false",
          "similarity": "boolean",
          "norms": "false",
          "fields": {
            "phonetic": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone",
              "search_analyzer": "dbl_metaphone_given_synonym"
            }
          }
        },
        "FatherSurnames": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index_options": "freqs",
          "store": "false",
          "similarity": "boolean",
          "norms": "false",
          "fields": {
            "phonetic": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone",
              "search_analyzer": "dbl_metaphone_surname_synonym"
            }
          }
        },
        "MotherGivenNames": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index_options": "freqs",
          "store": "false",
          "similarity": "boolean",
          "norms": "false",
          "fields": {
            "phonetic": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone",
              "search_analyzer": "dbl_metaphone_given_synonym"
            }
          }
        },
        "MotherSurnames": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index_options": "freqs",
          "store": "false",
          "similarity": "boolean",
          "norms": "false",
          "fields": {
            "phonetic": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone",
              "search_analyzer": "dbl_metaphone_given_synonym"
            }
          }
        },
        "SpouseGivenNames": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index_options": "freqs",
          "store": "false",
          "similarity": "boolean",
          "norms": "false",
          "fields": {
            "phonetic": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone",
              "search_analyzer": "dbl_metaphone_given_synonym"
            }
          }
        },
        "SpouseSurnames": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index_options": "freqs",
          "store": "false",
          "similarity": "boolean",
          "norms": "false",
          "fields": {
            "phonetic": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone",
              "search_analyzer": "dbl_metaphone_surname_synonym"
            }
          }
        },
        "ChildrenGivenNames": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index_options": "freqs",
          "store": "false",
          "similarity": "boolean",
          "norms": "false",
          "fields": {
            "phonetic": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone",
              "search_analyzer": "dbl_metaphone_given_synonym"
            }
          }
        },
        "BirthYears": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "BirthLocations": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "DeathYears": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "DeathLocations": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "MarriageLocations": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "MarriageYears": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "ResidenceLocations": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```